# Mysql search on multiple fields or on merged field

Tags: mysql, content-management-system

I have two tables (simplified):

```
---------
page
---------
id
deleted

---------
page_data
---------
id
id_page
value_int
value_float
value_text
value_date
value_serialized
value_something_else
```

page_data has a lot of different value types. I want to be able to search them all. Is this kind of approach okay?

```
SELECT * FROM page_data WHERE 
value_text LIKE '%" . $keyword . "%' 
OR value_int = ".$keyword."
OR ....
OR ....
```

Or would it be better/faster to add a "search" field in page (or page_data) table, and merge all to-be-searched-data into full text? I dont mind slower updating and more management. I want faster search.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It is okay to have a table with many columns. But more columns means more file IO and slower search. What I suggest is a different table with a reference to the large table and a TEXT COLUMN and use BOOLEAN FULL TEXT SEARCH like explained in the following url https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html

The FULL TEXT SEARCH makes searching even faster! An alternative way to use is SphinxSearch (www.sphinxsearch.com) which specialized in FULL TEXT SEARCH.